# Sharepoint/Infopath problems

Tags: infopath, 2016, data, connection

I have a problem with a customers InfoPath form after migrating it from SP2010 to 2016 onprem.

The choice columns won't work. Every time I try to attach an choice column to the form and try to publish I got this error message:

> The data source 'Connexion de données de choix' referenced in the form template is not valid or cannot be found.

Any idea what went wrong and how to solve the problem?

"Hi again, thanks for your answers.
My thought was that the problem had to do w some kind of data connection but I don't know how to fix it. Or for that matter find where to fix it. The list doesn't have any connections and the problem occurs only when I try to add  choice columns. When I open the tab Data/Data Connections it only shows Main and Alternative-connection and none of those two is possible to modify? See pic 2"
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not much info to give you guidance but my bet would be that your datasource is wrongly configured review the datasources for your form, probably it stills reference old 2013 farm.

Comment: IP is sometimes misbehaving. Have you tried this? : 1. Remove choice column. 2. Publish the form 3. Edit it again by adding choice and publish it again

Answer (score 0):

It seems some reference of that data connection (change connection to current farm after migration) still be there in form so once you remove the data connection, verify by rule inspector and also check rule of every fields and make sure you are not using this DC in any field.

Comment: Hi again, thanks for your answers.
My thought was that the problem had to do w some kind of data connection but I don't know how to fix it. Or for that matter find where to fix it. The list doesn't have any connections and the problem occurs only when I try to add  choice columns. When I open the tab Data/Data Connections it only shows Main and Alternative-connection and none of those two is possible to modify?